# How to Make sure that a particular method in a class is always the first being called?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit

I'm not too sure whether this is doable or not.

Currently I need to set the license information before the start of my test code, because these tests use a third party component library that requires me to initialize the license information. The license information needs to be set only once-- at the start of the running of the program.

But from what I understand, the philosophy of NUnit is that you can run a class, any class at any time, in any sequence, so although there is a `setup` method for each class, there isn't a `setup` method that runs at the start of the test for a test suite. But I may be wrong.

Is there anyway to make sure that a method is always the first being called during the whole test execution process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [SetupFixture](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4) attribute. You can define one setup function to run once for an entire namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I try to avoid setup and teardowns whenever possible. They tend to indicate (teardowns especially) that I am writing integration tests when I should be doing unit tests. 
However, I am known to your situation. When this is needed, I derive the testfixture from a class that handles the licensing.

```
public class LicencedTestFixture
{
    private LicenseComponent _licenseComponent;

    public LicencedTestFixture()
    {
        _licenseComponent = new LicenseComponent();
        _licenseComponent.Init();
    }

    ~LicencedTestFixture()
    {
        _licenseComponent.Shutdown();
    }

}
```

The test fixture just inherrit from the class, and that is all it needs to know:

```
[TestFixture]
public sealed class SomeTestFixture: LicencedTestFixture 
{}
```